# The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, model-view-controller

I am trying to sort this annoying bug and I cant figure out the root cause of this exception. I went through the stack trace and still wasnt able to figure out the problem. I checked for he required dlls and everything looks fine to me. Any suggestions or advise is highly appreciated.

Stack Trace:-

```
[FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +70
   System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +40
   System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +30
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow) +108
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +88
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup) +77
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +81
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k) +26
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory) +62
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key) +140
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r) +19
   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() +58
```

C# code -

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The exception is thrown at this specific line of code -

```
 public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }
```

//The following method returns null and throws exception at  `return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();`

Comment: Stack trace suggests that it fails to load database provider factory. So check if you have correct factory provider type wherever you set your oracle database provider (for example in app.config\web.config).

Comment: @Evk: <add name="******" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=****;Password=****;Data Source=*********"/> This is what I have in my web.config file

Comment: @Evk:- <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version= 4.0_4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>

Comment: Check that this type is correct: `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version= 4.0_4.112.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342`. For example that `_` in version looks suspicious. Also check this link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-managed-nuget-121021-2405792.txt.

Comment: @Evk Thanks that was the problem